# Masking animation not in sync

Tags: animation, modifiers, masking

I have done a masking animation using a Boolean. When the mask animates to reveal the bars, while the mask is a cube, moving in Z direction, it's showing increments of the objects I want to reveal. As seen in the example, increments of the object is shown bit by bit, until the other side is also revealed.

[image]

here is the animation:

https://streamable.com/0wn063

thank you.

Comment: hello, so what is your question? Also maybe share your file

Comment: The animation is lagging, and also both sides of the bars should be revealed while the mask is moving in Z direction. please share link so I can upload the file.

Comment: you should know the link now  ;)  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: here it is: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Kp6kvv0O" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Kp6kvv0O/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean doesn't like overlapping (I think it should be fixed in next versions), and the vertices on the left overlap the left face of your cube. Scale a bit (or move) on the X axis, or scale the cube, and it will work fine:

[image]

Comment: So simple, that was it, just  a bit of a scale! Thank you!